# inAppbrowser and webSql failure - cordova

Tags: cordova, web-sql, cordova-3, inappbrowser, cordova-plugins

I'm using cordova 3.4.1 and inAppbrowser.

I'm using webSql. At the `page load` I'm retriving some data from database. Works fine at that moment. Next with some button press, database entry is updated and a **inAppBrowser** window is opened.

```
tx.executeSql('UPDATE tb_comic SET page="'+image_id+'" WHERE id="'+id+'"');

ref=window.open('base.html','_blank','location=no, toolbar=yes, EnableViewPortScale=yes');
ref.addEventListener('exit', iabClose);


function iabClose(event)
{
     alert(event.type);
     ref.close();
     //location.reload(true);
}
```

Then after closing of the inAppBrowser window database starts to failt. Any query call doesn't give the expected result. I've tried to reload the page. Same result. Even after using `document.location` for going to a different page not working. Same unexpected result.

I commented out the inAppBrowser call `window.open`, then everything works fine. Every database retrieve is as expected. So my database code is perfect. `db` reference is held inside a variable perfectly. No problem there. But all problem starts after the ipAppBrowser call.

What is missing? Am I not closing the inAppBrowser correctly? What is the perfect way to use them both on the same page succesfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution to this problem at present as far as I've found.

View the answers on the following [link](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/inappbrowser_and_websql_failure?utm_source=notification&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=new_reply&utm_content=topic_link)

Way around:
[SQLite Plugin](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin)