# PhoneGap inApp Browser and WebSQL

Tags: cordova, web-sql, inappbrowser

I got a requirement analysis about **PhoneGap InApp Browser**.

I want to Know two things about InApp browsers..

1: `Can I call an Html file which located in my WWW folder using inApp Browser?`

2: `Can I create SQLite(WebSQL) and saving data from the Page which loaded in inApp browser?` 
( Here a page located in WWW folder name test.html and its loading in the inApp Browser. In this html file i coded for create a WebsQL and save data in to Database. is it possible?)

Please tell me about your opinion..

Comment: This isn't a well formed question, you haven't included any code that you've tried and you asking for opinions, neither of which form a good question on SO. I'll post an answer regardless because the solution is likely of interest to others.

Comment: @islanddavd As you can see from the question. "Requirement Analysis"? Surely this must be his work specific task.

Comment: Sorry Guys.. it was a sudden question which asking to me is it possible or not.. they give me 5 mins time to reply.. thats why I posted here for your valuable help. Last day i have worked the App successfully and its works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes you can call local page using

   `window.open('mypage.html', '_blank','location=no');`
2. Tricky answer. Yes you can create websql from that page inside inAppBrowser. how! search phonegap/cordova documentation. But... there is an issue using websql in inAppBrowser. Issue explained [here : inAppbrowser and webSql failure - cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030946/inappbrowser-and-websql-failure-cordova)

Issue described [here : look at the answer](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/inappbrowser_and_websql_failure?utm_source=notification&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=new_reply&utm_content=topic_link)

My suggestion wil be [use this : SQLite wrapper](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin)

Answer (score 1):

1: Yes, you can open an HTML file in your local www folder.

```
window.open('local-url.html', '_blank');
```

See [this link](https://wiki.apache.org/cordova/InAppBrowser)

2: Yes, there is a way to do it, though not through a formal API. TJ VanToll has a [full example](http://blogs.telerik.com/appbuilder/posts/13-12-23/cross-window-communication-with-cordova's-inappbrowser) available which uses a timeout to check for a value in the web page and then saves it to localStorage. You could then save it to your WebSQL.

```
<div data-role="view">
    <div>
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
        <button data-role="button" data-click="app.setName">Set Name</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    window.app = {
        load: function() {
            navigator.splashscreen.hide();
            new kendo.mobile.Application( document.body );
        },

        setName: function() {
            var win = window.open( "http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/K2yqc/show", "_blank",
                "EnableViewPortScale=yes" );

            win.addEventListener( "loadstop", function() {
                win.executeScript({ code: "localStorage.setItem( 'name', '' );" });
                var loop = setInterval(function() {
                    win.executeScript(
                        {
                            code: "localStorage.getItem( 'name' )"
                        },
                        function( values ) {
                            var name = values[ 0 ];
                            if ( name ) {
                                clearInterval( loop );
                                win.close();
                                $( "h1" ).html( "Welcome " + name + "!" );
                            }
                        }
                    );
                });
            });
        }
    };

    document.addEventListener( "deviceready", app.load );
</script>
```

And on the local web page, he includes:

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function() {
    localStorage.setItem( "name", this.name.value );
});
```